# Puissance 4 Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm trying to make a Puissance 4 game.

I Drew the game board then created 2 functions ; one to put player's pegs (set) using 3 var : raw, coloumn , and player.

The second Play : I give a column and it should find the firt free line.

But as I see it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mon Jeu JSV</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="plateforme">.</div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#plateforme table td {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color:white;

}
#plateforme table{
    background-color:blue;
}

#plateforme .joueur2{
    background-color:yellow;
}
#plateforme .joueur1{
    background-color:red;
}
```

JS

```
var col=6;
var lin=7;
var plateforme= document.querySelector('#plateforme');
var table= document.createElement("TABLE")
var tableauBi = [];
var turn=1;
for ( var i=0;i<lin;i++){
    var tr= document.createElement("TR");
    tableauBi[i] = [];
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for ( var j=0;j<col;j++){
        var td= document.createElement("TD");
        tr.appendChild(td);
        tableauBi[i][j]=td;
    }
}
plateforme.appendChild(table);
function set (row,column,player){
    var elt = tableauBi[row][column];
    elt.className = 'joueur'+ player;
    this.turn=3 - this.turn;
}
function play (column){
        var ligne;
    for ( var i=this.lin;i>0;i--){
        if (!this.tableauBi[i][column].className){//case vide
            ligne=i;
            break;
        }

    }
       this.set (ligne,column,this.turn);
}
play(6);
```

When I use play(6) : normally the first ligne in the 6th column get colorized.. But here no..

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn8n6dLv)

Comment: What have you done to debug it? Have you set a breakpoint in the `play` function and tried following it?

Comment: I have tried to debug. I'm a very begginer in Javascript.. It seems to me OK

Comment: Ok - I have a feeling I know what your problem might be. You create 6 columns so your `tableauBi` array is an array or arrays with each of those arrays having 6 members. You then try to address `tableauBi[i][6]`. Javascript arrays start at zero, not one. So the sixth column would be `tableauBi[i][5]` or `tableauBi[i][column-1]` (or just pass zero based columns in the first place). Simple debugging should show you this. Add a break point in your `play` function and see what `this.tableauBi[i][column]` actually evaluates to. Actually, you should have an error message in your console.

Comment: Actually, you have the same problem with `lin`. The last line in your array is going to be `lin-1`. Because again, it's zero based.

Comment: Ok I have Inderstood , thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not optimise your code at all, but here you go!

You had a bunch of scope errors, where you were using 'this' and I had to remove them all. When inside a function, 'this' refers to the scope of that function, so doing this.ligne won't access the 'ligne' variable which is outside the current function.

Also, be careful with your array indexes! If you have 6 rows, it means your indexes are from 0 to 5! Of course, you can use 1 to 6, but be careful to always substract one when accessing items in your list.

```
var col = 6;
var lin = 7;
var plateforme = document.querySelector('#plateforme');
var table = document.createElement("TABLE")
var tableauBi = [];
var turn = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("TR");
  tableauBi[i] = [];
  table.appendChild(tr);
  for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    tableauBi[i][j] = td;
  }
}
plateforme.appendChild(table);

function set(row, column, player) {
  var elt = tableauBi[row][column];
  elt.className = 'a joueur' + player;
  turn = 3 - turn;
}

function play(column) {
  var ligne;
  for (var i = lin-1; i >= 0; i--) {         // CAREFUL HERE, you were going out of bounds
    if (!tableauBi[i][column].className) { //case vide
      ligne = i;
      break;
    }

  }

  set(ligne, column, turn);
}
play(5);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn8n6dLv/2/#&togetherjs=b5zn77bsxe)

Comment: thanks , it work better ! :)